# 500: Internal Server Error on if(iffset($_GET())) on ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

This is really blowing my mind. I'm doing a simple login function using jquery ajax to store the some user information in session variables. However, every time I run it I get a 500.

php file:

```html
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_GET("FirstName"))) {

    $_SESSION["ShopUserFirstName"] = htmlentities($_GET['FirstName']);

    $_SESSION["ShopUserLastName"] = htmlentities($_GET['LastName']);

    $_SESSION["ShopUserID"] = htmlentities($_GET['UserID']);
    
    echo "You are now logged in. first name:". $_SESSION["ShopUserFirstName"]." last name:".$_SESSION["ShopUserLastName"]."id:". $_SESSION["ShopUserID"];
    
//} else {
//  echo "shoplogin error";
}
?>
```

However, I discovered if I remove this check:

```html
if (isset($_GET("FirstName"))) {
...
}
```

it works completely and everything is stored. Initially I was checking all 3 but either way it doesn't work. I've honestly never seen this behavior before, and I've used similar code many times in the past. Obviously I'd like to have that check there before I run any of the other code, can anyone  help me unravel this one?

Here is my javascript as well:

```js
    function login(first_name, last_name, user_id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "shoplogin.php",
            data: {'FirstName': first_name, 'LastName': last_name, 'UserID': user_id},
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                location.reload();
                
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

    }

    $(".user").click(function () {

        var user_id = this.getAttribute("id");

        var first_name = document.getElementById(user_id).getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
        var last_name = document.getElementById(user_id).getElementsByTagName('p')[1].innerHTML;

        login(first_name, last_name, user_id);
    });
```

Comment: [You're not doing **this**...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) which would have caught that syntax error. [GET/superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) are not a  "function" ;-)

Comment: `Server Error on if(iffset($_GET())) on ajax call` _`iffset($_GET())`_...

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
if (isset($_GET["FirstName"])) {
//             ^           ^
```

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

`$_GET` is the associative array of parameters sent in the `URL` so, you can get the param value by using `[]` operator.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: can you explain it for people who didn't see what was "extra"? edit: and missing ;-) thanks for your edit too.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` and `$_GET` are arrays, so you should use `['index']` to access their values.

In this case use `isset($_GET["FirstName"])`.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

Use [] instead of ()

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_GET["FirstName"])) {

    $_SESSION["ShopUserFirstName"] = htmlentities($_GET['FirstName']);

    $_SESSION["ShopUserLastName"] = htmlentities($_GET['LastName']);

    $_SESSION["ShopUserID"] = htmlentities($_GET['UserID']);

    echo "You are now logged in. first name:". $_SESSION["ShopUserFirstName"]." last name:".$_SESSION["ShopUserLastName"]."id:". $_SESSION["ShopUserID"];

//} else {
//  echo "shoplogin error";
}
?>
```

[GET Detalis](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Isn't this basically what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30892512/3150271) already said?